# Open Favourites Page in Safari with Javascript

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, javascript

I'm trying to make an extremely simple Safari extension that open the favourites page (the equivalent of Bookmarks > Show favourites), as that's what I think of as my home page and I'd like a button on the toolbar to do that, rather than have to do it via the menu.

Is there a javascript command to open this window or, failing that, to access the menu bar button so it can be clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the URL `topsites://`.

```
document.location.href = "topsites://";
```