# Open Favourites Page in Safari with search bar text

Tags: macos, safari, bookmarks

There is a question where someone answered `topsites://`:
[Open Favourites Page in Safari with Javascript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253389/open-favourites-page-in-safari-with-javascript/)

Is there any text which navigates to favourite bookmarks? Like `favourites://`?

I don't use Top Sites because it's so messed up and preview images are never correct and I want to change the homepage to the favourite bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set the favourites as the home page, you can do this from Preferences → General: set ‘New windows open with’ and ‘New tabs open with’ to ‘Favorites’.

[image]

There doesn't appear to be a URL to navigate to favourites. When I wrote [my answer in your linked question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/253400/37797), `topsites://` went to the favourites page if that's what you had selected, but nowadays it doesn't and there doesn't seem to be a replacement.

Comment: It's already set. I need this to have a button in safari which let me immediately go to favourites. There are Top sites button and Home Page button which you can configure on Safari but the Home page button is greyed out, I can't use it for this.